# C++ array of pointers to array on limited memory platform (arduino)

Tags: c++, embedded, arduino

for each letter in the alphabet i have an int-array declared like this:

```
int const  A[64] ={ 
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,
    0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,
    0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,
    0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,
    0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
};
```

then i create another array with pointers to these.

```
int const * text[] = { A, B, C };
```

this works fine, until that text array reaches a certain number of **different** entries.

for example this works:

```
int const * text[] = { A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A }; // could even go on much longer
```

but this crashes:

```
int const * text[] = { A, B, C, D }; // it seems the number of different entries matters
```

why is that? i thought that if it is pointers, then it should not matter what it points to it will always be of constant size?

note that this is run on the arduino platform, which has very limited memory.

Comment: Could you add more detailed explanation of the crash that happens?

Comment: sorry but i cant, the platform doesnt print any errors. the program just runs or doesnt run.

Comment: Are your arrays being referred to anywhere else than in the initialization of `text`?

Comment: The only line you change between it working and not working is defining the text variable?

Comment: What sort of output devices are you working with? Do you really have no debugger whatsoever? The first priority is to come up with a debugging strategy. Also, you burned 16 bits for every bit of typeface data, and used less than half the "canvas" for that "A"… perhaps 16K just for the typeface… this doesn't look like a truly "very limited memory" platform. That would indicate that a debugger is available.

Comment: Is the text variable being used anywhere in the program?

Comment: @Potatoswatter: i agree, this could of course be optimized a lot. but i am more interested in to why this is happening and not a solution to the problem.

Comment: @VaughnCato: yes, it is used in a loop to look up letters like this: `int const * const letter = text[i];`

Comment: So it is possible that the problem is in how text is being used.  You could try setting text to a value that doesn't crash, like {A,A,A,A}, and then adding another variable dummy_text that is set to {A,B,C,D} to see if the problem is really what you think it is.

Comment: @clamp: Once again, you need a debugging strategy, and from the little information you've given us, it appears to me that a debugger should be available. Anyway, can you be more specific than "an Arduino"? Is there a particular reason you're not using a debugger?

Comment: If memory is really that tight, you could use a char array. And using bitmaps, this would only cost 8 chars per glyph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that lookup into an array with identical elements is being optimized; If `int const *text[];` were declared in a header file and compiled (defined) in a separate object file, you would likely see the same problem. The linker is doing the best it can, but all that data is likely overlapping with the heap / stack space.

At least with avr-libc (using avr-gcc, avr-binutils), there are macros, or variable attributes, that can place this sort of constant data in the much larger, read-only program space (flash ROM).

Comment: so you mean that the compiler/linker is optimizing unused letters away?

Comment: @clamp - yes, if that symbol is never referenced. If the compiler knows that a lookup will return 'A', it will fold that constant at compile-time; it need not perform an actual lookup.